# Rate a post only once per user in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have trouble in allowing users to rate a post. My task is to enable the user to rate a post only once. On the show page, the post I have includes radio buttons for rating. If the user tries to rate for the second time it needs to update the previous rating done by the user for the same post. The issue I am facing is that user is able to rate a post multiple times. How to resolve this?

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  has_many :ratings
end
```

Post model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ratings
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Ratings model

```
class Rating < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In the post controllers i have used nested attributues for ratings.

```
def show
  @post = @topic.posts.find(params[:id])
  @rate = @post.ratings.all
  @rate = Rating.where(post_id: @post.id).group("rate").count
end

private def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, ratings_attributes: [:rate])
end
```

The show page of post include the creating of rating using `<fieldset>`:

```
<%= form_for [@topic, @post] do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :ratings, @post.ratings.build do |builder| %>
    <fieldset>
      <% for i in 1..5 %>
        <%= builder.radio_button :rate, i %><%= i %>
      <% end %>
    </fieldset>
  <% end %>
  <%=f.submit "Rate" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use first or initialize like this

```
   @rating=Rating.where(post_id: @post.id,user_id: current_user).first_or_initialize
```

Answer (score 2):

First, add validation to the Rating to enforce uniqueness on the combination of user and post. This will stop a duplicate rating ever being created.

`validates_uniqueness_of :post_id, scope: :user_id`

Then, in the action that saves the rating, first check if there is a record that can be updated, else create a new one.

```
@rating = Rating.find_or_initialize_by(user: @user, post: @post)
@rating.rate = params[:rate]
@rating.save
```

This might not be perfect syntax, but you should get the idea about what you are trying to do and can adjust to match your code.

Comment: In which controller i need to check the condition that u provided??

Comment: The first line of code goes in the model, the second part in the controller.

Comment: In which controller i need to give it